# Android emulator automatically launched with Jenkins doesn't react like the one launched manually

Tags: c#, jenkins, android-emulator, appium

When my Appium serveur is launched, I use this BAT file i made and it works:

```
start cmd.exe /k "emulator -avd ff"
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 60 > nul
start cmd.exe /k "adb shell input keyevent 82" //unlock the screen
C:\Users\etudes.ext46\Downloads\NUnit-2.6.4\NUnit-2.6.4\bin\nunit-console.exe C:\Users\etudes.ext46\Downloads\NUnit-2.6.4\NUnit-2.6.4\bin\apk\UnitTestProject1.dll
start cmd.exe /k "taskkill /F /IM emulator-x86.exe"
start cmd.exe /k "taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe"
```

I try to automate it with Jenkins :
[image]

The emulator is launched, but the test failed.
This is the error i get :

```
    Errors and Failures:
1) TearDown Error : AppiumSample.ASSI2.AssistanceV2
   SetUp : System.InvalidOperationException : A new session could not be created. (Original error: spawn OK) (33)
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumDriver`1..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumDriver`1..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Android.AndroidDriver`1..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at AppiumSample.ASSI2.SetupTest()
--TearDown
   at AppiumSample.ASSI2.TeardownTest()
```

Looks like a session is allready open, but i don't understand where.
When I manually start the emulator and use Jenkins only for the Nunit test, everything works.

Comment: can you call the batch file from jenkins ? See if it runs then. If not then it might have to do something with the access rights.

Comment: I can call it without rights problems, i'm gonna try to launch Appium directly in Jenkins

Comment: @Vwaib Everythings work with my BAT file, but with Jenkins i have this error :
SetUp : OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->